# issue with the css and html div p tags

Tags: css, html

As i am working on one of the page in which i am getting some strange problem. Like i have designed a page in which the image comes at left side and the corresponding text for the image will come right side. But the issue is the text which i am trying to select is not selecting with the mouse. And also the test for the image comes by leaving one div. Please see this link for better understanding the problem http://www.startonlinegames.com/download1 Please see my code below.

Comment: Why you double posted? Are you gonna erase this one to right away?

Comment: I have deleted the previous post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image description is displaying next to another image. You need to change the placing of divs. I have made slight changes in your code. Check the one block reference below. And remove the empty p tag in description

```
<div style="float:left; width:462px; height:196px; margin:5px; border:solid #b8cbd2 1px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px">
        <div style="float:right; width:230px">
        <p>         
        </p><div style="background:#fff; margin-left:5px; margin-top: 5px; width:230px; height:150px;">

       <p><b>Name:</b>Astrobot</p>
        <p><b>Description:</b> Defend our lunar-base and destroy the alien robots nest!</p>
            <p><b>Dimensions:</b> 600x600</p>
       </div>

          </div><div style="background:#fff; margin-left:5px; width:225px; height:150px; margin-top:5px">
        <a href="http://www.startonlinegames.com/play/Astrobot"><img src="http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/images/538263_Upload.gif" width="225" height="150" border="0" class="imgShadowEffect"></a>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top: 10px">
            <a href="http://www.startonlinegames.com/play/Astrobot"><img src="http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/play.png" border="0" width="117" height="30"></a><a href="download/zip/538263_Astrobot.rar"><img src="http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/download.png" border="0" width="117" height="30"></a>
        </div>         

        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sowmya, thanks for the response. but the thing here is its not in proper format..please check once..

Comment: I have edited the answer. I have added only first block code. You need to change that for all blocks. you can check the effect of selecting text in the image attached

Comment: open the image in new tab and check the inspect element code structure

Answer (score 0):

```
Changes in first column. same as change others columns.  


<div style="float:left; width:462px; height:196px; margin:5px; border:solid #b8cbd2 1px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px">
                <div style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-left: 5px; width: 225px; height: 150px; margin-top: 5px; float: left;">
                <a href="http://www.startonlinegames.com/play/Astrobot"><img width="225" height="150" border="0" class="imgShadowEffect" src="http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/images/538263_Upload.gif"></a>
                </div>


               <div style="float: left; width: 222px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px;">
                <div style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: 5px; height: 150px; width: 220px;">

               <p><b>Name:</b>Astrobot</p>
                <b>Description:</b> Defend our lunar-base and destroy the alien robots nest!                <p><b>Dimensions:</b> 600x600</p>
               </div>

                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-top: 5px">
                    <a href="http://www.startonlinegames.com/play/Astrobot"><img width="117" height="30" border="0" src="http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/play.png"></a><a href="download/zip/538263_Astrobot.rar"><img width="117" height="30" border="0" src="http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/download.png"></a>
                </div>


                </div>
```